# expected unqualified-id before 'default'

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code, I feel that it has a quite simple fix but i can't find it.

/*
Copyright (c) 2016-2017  Moddable Tech, Inc.

```
 This file is part of the Moddable SDK Runtime.

 The Moddable SDK Runtime is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 (at your option) any later version.

 The Moddable SDK Runtime is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

 You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 along with the Moddable SDK Runtime.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
```

*/

/*
ArduCAM Mini driver
2 Megapixel - OV2640 controller chip
*/

> export ***default***  class ArduCAM "xs_arducam_destructor" {
> constructor(dictionary) "xs_arducam";
> capture() "xs_arducam_capture";
> read(buffer)  "xs_arducam_read";
> close() "xs_arducam_close";
> }

/*
dictionary:

```
    {width: 320, height: 240, format: "rgb565be"}
    {width: 320, height: 240, format: "rgb565le"}
    {width: 160, height: 120, format: "jpeg"}
```

*/

I don't have much experience with javascript coding and just want to finish this code for my arduino. I haven't really tried many different methods to fix the problem, I looked it up but no dice.

Comment: You mention a problem but you don't say which one. Also there seems to be a probem with your code formatting, you could edit your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.